# getOAuthRequestToken returns null while using twitter4j

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I am using twitter4j for authorization purpose for my android application.

I have stored my consumer key and consumer secret key in resources directory.

I have created a twitter and RequestToken objects like this

```
private Twitter twitter;
private RequestToken currentRequestToken;
```

I have a method which will fetch OAuth Request tokens from twitter for me.

```
public String beginAuthorization() {
    try {
        if( currentRequestToken == null) {
           currentRequestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();
        }
        String authURL = currentRequestToken.getAuthorizationURL();
        return authURL; 
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        Log.i("NOTES", "In the twitter exception");
        e.printStackTrace();  // print simple stack trace on 
    }
    return null;
}
```

The error i am getting here is Null Pointer exception at line where i call the 
`twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();` i have tried looking at code snippets and searched online 
everywhere i find the same method call, For me its not working and throwing exception.

I am not able to figure out what is the problem here, I have set `INTERNET` permissions in the manifest file.

Comment: I am facing same issue. It was working before.

Comment: Are you implemented using callback url

Comment: Did you execute twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(); in a AsyncTask? Do you have error log?

Answer (score 0):

Replace old twitter4j.jar library with the latest twitter4j 3.0.5jar.

link:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/dt4suej0zkoi997/twitter4j-core-3.0.5.jar